# Getting a Website's Title and Favicon with C++

Tags: c++, title

I'm trying to make a Web-Browser with C++. Its going along well, though I want to add the Favicon and want to get the Title so then I can make my Form's name:  - UFox (Random name there. :P It's not the actual name though.) Any Idea on how you can do this? (And ik this is possible. Just Idk how to do it. :C)

Comment: Get the content of the `<title>` element for the title. Get `/favicon.ico` or `<link rel="shortcut icon">` for the favicon.

Comment: @minitech, Is that in C++, or HTML? If C++, how would I do this?

Comment: You're building a web browser. Yes, it is in HTML. How is the HTML document represented?

Comment: @minitech, I dont think your understanding me. (Or, I'm just dumb. xD) Trying to get the Websites title name with c++.

Comment: No, I think you're just not understanding how to build a web browser. You have to work with an HTML document, so where is it?

Comment: @miniech, I'm not working with a HTML document. :P This is just the simplest type of web-browser. All you have to do is add like 3 buttons, 1 text bar, and 1 Web-Browser. Then the cod for the back button would be: WebBrowser->GoBack(); I got the title in Visual Basic once. But It's not the same as C++

Comment: Yes, you are working with an HTML document, or you are not building a browser. Are you using a pre-built `WebBrowser` component? There will be a property somewhere to access the underlying DOM document, or at least some property to access the title and favicon. If you are certain it provides none of these, then you need a new web browser component.

Comment: @minitech, Well, I guess I am using a pre-built one, now that I think about it. It comes with Microsoft's Visual C++. But, I don't see a property to access the DOM document, or the Title and Favicon. (If I did, I won't be here. xD) But I do see 2 propertys called (Application settings) and (DataBindings)

Answer (score 1):

To get the favicon, it will be located at `http://www.example.com/favicon.ico`. Use your system for retrieving the HTML to retrieve the `.ico` file. The title is located in the HTML itself, under the tag `<title>...</title>`.

I hope that answers your question! Good luck on your web browser!

Comment: The favicon is not *necessarily* there, and the OpenGraph title is not the actual title of the document.